# Which hotels in Amsterdam have hot tubs in the rooms?

Tags: amsterdam

I am looking for a hotel in Amsterdam, for around £150 a night or less. It MUST have a hot tub/jacuzzi in the hotel room. It needs to be as close to the centre as possible. It would be an advantage if it had a swimming pool, nice bar etc... Any suggestions??

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Unfortunately your question are likely to be put on hold as an opinion based as per our [Help Center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Just use google, there are a lot of hotels that claim having one in at least some of the rooms. Do double check on a review site or a hotel booking site. All hotels on and within the ring of canals, and quite a few just outside it, are central.

Comment: I have searched and searched and have found none that are in my price range. I just thought there was a chance someone would see this and happen to know one. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Prices  in Amsterdam are generaly high. Specially if booking last minute.

Answer (score 2):

The Hotel Roemer, Roemer Visscherstraat 8-10, just completed an expansion in an out building which added twelve deluxe rooms.  The so-called 'Junior Suite' contains a jacuzzi, there's an image [here](http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/01/9d/f3/48/the-junior-suite-jacuzzi.jpg).

The site [Eccentric Hotels](http://www.eccentrichotels.com/hotels-with-in-room-jacuzzi/) has a page devoted to in-room jacuzzis and there we can see that the Toren Hotel Canal Ring has [a great jacuzzi](http://www.eccentrichotels.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/deluxe-room-jacuzzi-v1536931-34-1600.jpg).

The Trip Advisor site has a page called the [20 Best Amsterdam Hotels with Jacuzzi](http://www.tripadvisor.com/HotelsList-Amsterdam-Hotels-With-Jacuzzi-zfp14367.html).

Comments have suggested that you can also accomplish a basic Google search. If you want to search for more, these are the 5 star hotels in Amsterdam...

[image]

Source: "Hello Amsterdam" magazine, Sep/Oct 2015, issue #4, published by http://helloamsterdam.nl/en/

The room prices at these hotels will require flexibility with your GBP 150 budget, but the final price will depend upon the arrangements you make with the hotel, your credentials, and so on.  I cannot list their prices here because they are massively volatile and season dependent and you did not provide that information in your question.